# why does the software here keep deleting my comments

Tags: discussion

whenever I post a comment it gets deleted within a minute

what is happening, why do all my comments get deleted?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I deleted your comments because they were being unpleasant towards another community member.

Your answers are getting deleted because they aren't answering the question.

For example:

> Does it float on water? That might help tranporting it.

This is a question, not an answer and also repeats what several other answers already say.

> lol no why would that be possible

Also not an answer, not really even a question.

> A bit like I mentioned in my answer on your other question, many power sources just add lots of weight to your city and produce little energy in comparison to the amount require to suspend a big city.
>
> For every extra power source you add, you add weight, so you need more energy to support the weight, so you need more power sources..... it is vicious circle.
>
> There is balance to be struck and it lies in the realms where you produce lots and lots of power. Perhaps best method would be by matter convertion.

This on the other hand is a good answer. It addresses the question, it provides valid reasoning as to why the answer is true and raises a good point. As a result this answer has been upvoted and you've recieved rep for it.

All I can say is that if you keep writing answers like this one you will gain rep. If you write them like the first two then they will be deleted or you may well be downvoted and lose rep.

Once you reach 50 rep (which only needs a couple more upvotes so you are close) then you can comment everywhere, which is what you seem to be trying to do in a number of these cases. Comments are much more relaxed about what can be posted, although we still try and keep the site clean so long discussions should happen in chat.

You need to remember that we like to try and keep the site clean. Questions should be clear, answers should answer the question. Anything else makes the site a lot less useful.

It's good that you want to get involved, we're happy that you seem to like the site, but to keep the site useful we need to make sure that the quality on answers is high and that every answer really is an answer.